# PHP and MySQL with infinite loop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating a system where I am sending a token (generated in PHP and stored in a MySQL db) with a form.on submission I take that token and validate it along with credentials.

The problem is with the class file that is handling all this. The function `set_token()` is behaving absurdly.

It is setting the token every 10-12 secs and storing it table infinitely. Even after I closed the browser. The connection is neither terminated and the function is being called again and again from sources I don't know.

This is the class file..

```
class auth {
    private $uplink;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->uplink=new mysqli(HOST_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        $this->uplink->close();
    }

    public function query_noreturn($q) {
       $query = $q;

       if($this->uplink->query($q)){
          return true;
       }
       else {
          return false;
       }
    }

   public function gen($len){
    $data="ASDFGHJKLQPOWERITYULZXCVMBNasdlkjfhgzmnxcbvqpwoeiuty_1597863420@";
    $rgen='';
    for($i=0;$i<=$len;$i++){
        $rgen.=$data[rand(0,strlen($data)-1)];
    }
    $generate=hash('sha256',$rgen);
    return $generate;
        }

    public function set_token(){
        $token=$this->gen(20);
        $f=time();
        $query="INSERT INTO token_auth(token_val,token_tm)"."VALUES('$token','$f')";
        if(($this->query_noreturn($query))){
            return $token;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }   
    }
}
```

and this is the php file which is setting it for the first time.

```
$auth = new auth();
$key = $auth->set_token();
```

Comment: The code is still running after you close the browser? How are you sure of that? I don't get enough context here to provide a clear answer yet.

Comment: @Zarathuztra becoz after closing the browser even then the my table is getting entries.

Comment: Weirdest thing I've heard in a while. You're sure you don't have any other connections maintained in perhaps a window you can't see, other browser, anything?

Comment: `$token=$this->gen(20);` where is this function?

Comment: What if you log on to your server and you type `$ sudo service apache2 stop` ?

Comment: @Zarathuztra i am running this on xampp on my system and no browser is running neither any other web app running.

Comment: @sid So if you stop just apache in the xampp console? (since Jivan's answer wont' work on windows)

Comment: @Nouphal.M edited it.now with gen() function.

Comment: @Zarathuztra after stopping apache phpmyadmin wont work.

Comment: @sid Don't use PHPmyadmin, use the mysql console directly. Just open up a command prompt and the mysql command should already be in PATH. View your tables that way.

Comment: @Zarathuztra after stopping apache it is not making entries

Comment: Are you using any sort of javascript timers?

Comment: @Nouphal.M no timers at all..it is simple javascript form submission through ajax.But before even submitting all this is happening.

Comment: @Zarathuztra upvote it so others can also answer..it is looking interesting.

Comment: check in firebug or webdeveloper console how many ajax calls are been sent..

Comment: @Nouphal.M i am not sending any calls..its is justing doing it with php.i am not sending any ajax requests firtshand

Comment: you submit it via js right? try submitting without js and check.. or else if you are using js form submit just check the console to see whats happening in background

Comment: @sid For sure dude. Unless we're missing something or the question is worded wrong, this is definitely one of those WTF questions.
OP: Have you tried manually killing the connection to see if maybe there is something wrong with the PHP install you using and how it's handling __destruct()?

Comment: @Zarathuztra i even used __destruct().it is also not killing the connection!.

Comment: @Nouphal.M ya i am using js to submit the form but all this starts happening before form submission.

Comment: @sid, I mean manually calling $this->uplink->close() from some other means, just in case the version of PHP you have installed isn't handling __desctruct() correctly. I'm still baffled as to how the script could possible keep running after your session is totally severed unless there is some strange oddity in your Apache installation.

Comment: @Zarathuztra i even used $this->uplink->close(); in set token() so after setting it closes connection.But still not stopping.

Comment: @Zarathuztra are u suggesting to reinstall apache?

Comment: @sid Not necessarily, I'm just trying to think of all possible causes. If the script is actually still running even after the connection is closed, then something is holding that thread open and executing, whether it's the PHP interpreter (less likely) or Apache (more likely). Try a re-install.

Comment: @Zarathuztra ok thanks.can u suggest any good read for php and mysql connections.

Comment: @sid Well, given your above issue, I'm not sure what to recommend. A good place to start would probably be just the documentation from MySQL directly regarding connections.